# How can Thom observe the battle on the valley from the top of Shayol Ghul synchronously?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

We know that the nearer you are to Shayol Ghul, the slower the time flows, especially at the last war while Rand is in the cave, struggling with Dark One.

The time's speed is largely different between the top of the mountain and the bottom of the mountain.

We know this, because there are a lot of references on the last book and one of them says this: Some Aiel guards are surprised to see the time on the valley had passed twice longer than some high level of the mountain where they did their watch duty.

My question is this:

Thom is at the edge of the cave on Shayol Ghul and guarding the entrance and observing the battle on the valley. The time must be passing way much slower than it passes on the valley.

It also seems that Thom never needs to sleep while Rand, Moiraine and Nynaeve are in the cave because it just takes a short time. But meanwhile on the valley, lots of days pass til Rand and other come out of the cave.

So Tom should observe that any movement on the valley is really very fast. And on the contrary, if anyone from the valley looks up at Thom they should observe that Thom is moving really very slowly. I can't imagine the observing of days and nights.

But I don't see any references to this in the book. Am I missing something?

Comment: Speed of light is a constant in our universe as far as we know. In Robert Jordan's world, where people can shape the very fabric of the universe, perhaps Shayol Ghul can even effect the speed of light. If this were the case, then to Tom everything would appear to move at normal speeds no matter how close or far away from him they are.

Comment: @Firebat nevertheless how can it be synchronous? It's only a few hours for Thom but he sees more than a week's events. I don't get it.

Comment: @Firebat It wouldn't work like that, it would maybe make the light not to red/blueshift when getting from places with other pace of passing time. An explanation may be that the world was getting closer to World of Dreams where time was fluid and laws of physics hardly worked.